# AWS Lambda - editing functions outside of amazon.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

I'm new to **AWS Lambda** and I recently started developing Lambda functions together with API Gateway and RDS as a simple backend-solution.

I've been searching for an IDE where I can edit the code of the functions. I've tried Cloud9 but I'm looking for an environment that's not browser-based and with an app for mac. IntelliJ seems like an option too but it's a bit expensive for my needs.

Any free / cheap alternatives for just editing the code of the Lambda-functions in an independent app for mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most IDEs will have an extension for AWS/Lambda integration.

If you're looking for free IDES:

- VS Code has an [official toolkit](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudiocode/)
- Sublime Text has a [plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AWS%20Lambda)

Comment: Sublime is perfect for me. Thank you for the quick and precise answer!